PgSQL returns results at different speeds from same execution plan, but different query using CTE vs. nested select, why?
db=> explain analyze with data as (select a, b, c from D where e='something') select * from Data;
                                                              QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on D (cost=0.00..3060987.06 rows=1955179 width=42) (actual time=0.022..81146.222 rows=2027407 loops=1)
   Filter: ((e)::text = 'something'::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 9757878
 Planning Time: 0.083 ms
 Execution Time: 89924.754 ms
(5 rows)

db=> explain analyze select * from (select a, b, c from D where e='something') x;
                                                              QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on documentsubjecthistory  (cost=0.00..3060987.06 rows=1955179 width=42) (actual time=0.025..81148.606 rows=2027407 loops=1)
   Filter: ((subjectentitycodesystem)::text = '2.16.840.1.113883.6.69'::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 9757878
 Planning Time: 0.105 ms
 Execution Time: 89925.772 ms
(5 rows)

However, when I actually run the first one with the with Data (...) select * from Data CTE, the results actually only come after these 89 seconds, while when I run the select * from (...) x, I get the initial page rapidly.
I have \set FETCH_COUNT 1000 in .psqlrc

What Postgres version? What client software do you use to run the queries?

Perhaps the first 1000 rows that match the condition are early in the table in one case and late in the other.

maybe my exes deceive me, but arent the  Execution Time: almost identical
?

psql before version 17 will ignore FETCH_COUNT for queries that don't start with the keyword select (the v16 doc says: the results of SELECT queries are fetched and displayed in groups of that many rows, and this SELECT must be interpreted literally).
In this question, the first statement starts with with and the second with select, so psql v16 or older sends the first query unmodified and processes all its results in one step. The first result is only available when the whole result set has been retrieved in memory. On the other hand, the second query is transformed into:
BEGIN
DECLARE _psql_cursor NO SCROLL CURSOR FOR <query>
  FETCH FORWARD 1000 FROM _psql_cursor (repeated until no more rows to fetch)
CLOSE _psql_cursor
COMMIT

Each block of results is available immediately after each FETCH iteration.
Starting with psql v17, the implementation no longer uses a cursor; it honors FETCH_COUNT by using the new chunked rows mode , which works with all queries. So presumably you would see both queries handing out the firsts results quickly with a newer psql.
PostgreSQL v17 was released only two days ago at this point, but this feature doesn't need an updated server, only the newest client.
